# Sort a vector of structs by an f64 value

Tags: sorting, rust, vector, struct, floating-point

I am trying to sort a vector of `Substance` structs:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialOrd, PartialEq)]
struct Substance {
    price: i32,
    mass_kg: i32,
    price_per_kg: f64,
}
```

by `price_per_kg` my current sorting code is:

```
// `substances` is a `vec` of `Substance`'s
substances.sort_unstable_by_key(|price_per_kg| price_per_kg);
```

This fails as the method requires the `Ord` trait. However, as `f64` doesn't implement `Eq` I can't derive `Ord` and therefore I seemingly can't use this method.

Could you please let me know how I can do this sorting? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`f64` doesn't implement `Ord` because of `NaN`... In practice,this means that Rust expects you to instruct it about how to handle if you need to compare such a float. An easy way is to assume you don't have any `NaN` value and panicking if you do, as follows:

```rust
impl Ord for Substance {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(self, other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

This way, you naturally extend the partial ordering ignoring an annoyance of working with floats.

Comment: That makes sense, but the code you suggest still requires the `Eq` trait, which I do not have and cannot derive.

Comment: `Eq` is just an empty marker trait, so it's easy to implement yourself: `impl Eq for Substance {}` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=9482a28c6782ffd64e7762ee8af288c7)).

Comment: @Pioneer_11 also note that there are some crates that already do these kind of solutions, and that also offer other solutions (for instance, consider `NaN` as the greatest float), so using them is probably more convenient. I just gave you this code as a pedagogical example. See [`ordered_float`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/) for instance.

Comment: For instance, you may want to represent a float as a `Option<NonNan>`, which is a better way to encode the failure float `NaN`, but which is also (very slightly) slower if you do heavy computations on floats.